# Show that $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $G_{1}(V)$ are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry, grassmannian

Be $V$ a real vector space of dimension $n+1$ defined over $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Build up a differential structure on $\mathbb{P}(V)$, the projective space on $V$. Show that there is a diffeomorphism between $\mathbb{P}(V)$ and $G_{1}(V_{})$ (where $G_{1}(V_{})$ is the Grassmann manifold made up of vector subspaces of dimension $1$ ).

**Definition 1** (Projective space $\mathbb{P}(V)$).
Be $V$ a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. The *projective space* $\mathbb{P}(V)$ of V is the set $\mathbb{P}(V)$ of the equivalence class of $V\setminus\{O\}$ with respect the the equivalence relation $\sim$ defined by $v\sim w$ iff $v=\lambda w$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{K}\setminus\{O\}$.

**Definition 2** (Grassmann Manifold $G_{k}(V_{n})$)
Be $V_{n}$ a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$, and be $k$, such that $1\leq k\leq n-1$. The *Grassmann Manifold $G_{k}(V_{n})$* of the $k$planes of $V$ is the set $G_{k}(V_{n})$ of the vector subspaces of $V$ of dimension $k$.

The previous exercise is taken from the book: Marco Abate, Francesca Tovena, Geometria differenziale.

We have to find out a map $F: G_{1}(V)\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V)$ such that $\phi\circ F\circ\chi^{-1}: \chi(W)\rightarrow \phi(U)$, is of $C^{\infty}$ where both $(\chi, W)$ and $(\phi, U)$ are charts for
$G_{1}(V)$ and $\mathbb{P}(V)$  respectively.

Let be $V$ a vector space of dimension of $n+1$ over the field of real numbers.
Once that a basis for $V$ has been fixed, it is possible to associate to each vector the coefficients with respect to the basis. Hence, for a generic vector $v\in V$, we have that its representation with respect to the basis is given by the following numbers $(x^{0},\dots,x^{n})$.

Considering $\mathbb{P}(V)$, we will indicate as $[x^{0}:\dots:x^{n}]$ the projection on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ of $(x^{0},\dots,x^{n})$.

The charts for $\mathbb{P}(V)$ are given by $$U_{j}=\{[x^{0}:\dots:x^{n}]\in\mathbb{P}(V)|x^{j}\neq0\}$$

with the transistion maps $\phi_{j}: U_{j}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $$\phi_{j}([x^{0}:\dots:x^{n}]) = \Big(\frac{x^{0}}{x^{j}},\dots,\frac{x^{j-1}}{x^{j}},\frac{x^{j+1}}{x^{j}},\dots, \frac{x^{j+1}}{x^{j}}\Big)$$
and their inverse $$\phi^{-1}(y) = [y^{0}:\dots:y^{j-1}:1:y^{j+1}:y^{n}]$$.

The charts $(U_{0}, \phi_{0})$ and $(U_{1}, \phi_{1})$ are compatible: in fact $$\phi_{0}(U_{0}\cap U_{1})= \{y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\ s.t.  y^{1}\neq 0\} =\phi_{1}(U_{0}\cap U_{0})$$ and $$\phi_{0}\circ\phi^{-1}_{1}(y)=\big(\frac{1}{y^{1}},\frac{y^{2}}{y^1},\dots,\frac{y^{n}}{y^1}\big)$$.
The same holds for the remaining charts.
The topology of this manifold coincides with the quotient topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{O\}$.

The charts of the Grassmann manifold $G_{k}(V)$ are defined as $$W_{Q}=\{P\in G_{k}(V)|P\cap Q = O\}$$
where $Q$ is the subspace of $V$ of dimension $n+1-k$ such that $V = Q\oplus P$.
Let we fix an element $P_{0}$ of $W_{Q}$ and be $A\in Hom(P_{0},Q)$.

The charts $G_{k}(V)$ are $\psi_{Q}:A\rightarrow W_{Q}$ $$\psi_{Q}(A)= (\iota + A)(P_{0})$$

where $\iota:P_{0}\rightarrow V$ is the inclusion map.
Since given $p\in W_{Q}$ every $p_{0}\in P_{0}$ can be decomposed in a unique way as $p_{0} = p +q$ with $p\in P$ and $q\in Q$. Hence $A$ can be defined in an explicit way as $A(p_{0})=-q$.

Be $\chi_{Q}=\psi^{-1}_{Q}$. Since fixing the basis for both $P_{0}$ and $Q_{0}$  is possible to identify $Hom(P_{0},Q)$ with $\mathbb{R}^{k\times (n+1-k)}$ the couples $(\chi_{Q},W_{Q})$ are $k\times(n+1-k)$ charts.
It is possible to prove that they are compatible.

Regarding the topology, let $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^{k\times (n+1)}$ be the set of linearly independent n-tuples of elements of $\mathbb{R}^{k\times (n+1)}$. Then there is a surjection $p:Y\rightarrow G_{k}(V_{})$ sending an element of $Y$ to its span. The topology on $G_{k}(V_{})$ is the quotient topology for this map $p$ (considering $Y$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{k\times (n+1)}$)

Coming to the exercise, by setting $k=1$, we have that $G_{k}(V_{})$ is made up of $1-dimensional$ vector subspaces of $V$ (i.e. vectors of dimension $ n+1 $). Hence,  we can define the map $F =(\pi\circ id_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}})$ where:

- $id_{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}}: V_{} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the canonical isomorphism between $V$, the vector spece defined over the field $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and the field itself.
- $\pi : V\setminus\{O\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V)$ is the projection of $v\in V\setminus\{O\}$ onto $\mathbb{P}(V)$ i.e. $\pi : v\rightarrow [v]$

Since $F$ it is the composition of differential maps between manifolds (M.Abate, F.Tovena, Geometria differenziale pg 77), we have that $F$ it is a diffeomorphism.

Let me know what you think about that.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should give the precise definitions of $\mathbb P(V)$ and $G_1(V)$ (including the topology and the smooth structure). As it is, your question will not receive a precise answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've tried to make my statement clearer. Please, suggest to me other clarifications if they are needed.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(V_{n+1})$ and $G_{1}(V_{n})$ are not diffeomorphic (what happens if $n = 1$?). As in the title you need the same vector space $V$ for both sets. Omit the indices and say that $\dim V = {n+1}$. I would even suggest to take $V =\mathbb R^{n+1}$; this is not  a real restriction. Also you do not need a more general field  $\mathbb K$ here. The definition of the charts on $G_1(V)$ is confusing. What is $Q$? You say it is "the complementar subspace of $V$ of dimension $n$ (here $V$ has dimension $n+1$)".  Do you mean that $Q$ is any $n$-dimensional subspace of $V  =\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: Why is $W_Q$ open? And a chart should be a homeomorphism $\psi_Q : W_Q \to \mathbb R^n$. What is $k$ in $\mathbb R^{k(n-k)}$? And what is $k(n)$?

Comment: The Grassmann manifold is a manifold of dimension $k\times (n-k)$. Hence the charts are defined as homeomorphisms $\chi: W_{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k\times (n-k)}$( this fact follows from the general definition of $n$ chart $(U,\phi)$, for a manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ ).